# ML.NET Dynamic InputModel

Tags: ml.net

I'm using ML.NET to do Multiclass Classification. I have 3 use cases with different input models(different number of columns and data types) and there will be more to come so it doesn't make sense to have to create a physical file for each input models for every new use cases. I'd like to have preferably just ONE physical file that can adapt to any models if possible and if not, dynamically create the input model at runtime based on the column definitions defined out of a json string retrieved from a table in a Sql Server DB. Is this even possible? If so, can you share the sample codes?

Here are some snippets of the prediction codes that I'd like to make generic :-

```
    public class DynamicInputModel
    {

        [ColumnName("ColumnA"), LoadColumn(0)]
        public string ColumnA { get; set; }


        [ColumnName("ColumnB"), LoadColumn(1)]
        public string ColumnB { get; set; }


    }

    PredictionEngine<DynamicInputModel, MulticlassClassificationPrediction> predEngine = _predEnginePool.GetPredictionEngine(modelName: modelName);

    IDataView dataView = _mlContext.Data.LoadFromTextFile<DynamicInputModel>(
                        path: testDataPath,
                        hasHeader: true,
                        separatorChar: ',',
                        allowQuoting: true,
                        allowSparse: false);


    var testDataList = _mlContext.Data.CreateEnumerable<DynamicInputModel>(dataView, false).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do DynamicInput, however you can create pipelines from one input schema and create multiple different models based on the labels/features.  I have an example below that does that...two label columns and you can pass in an array of what feature columns to use for the model.  The one downside to this approach is that the input schema (CSV/Database) has to be static (not change on load):

https://github.com/bartczernicki/MLDotNet-BaseballClassification